# Автоматическая обработка ajax форм на событии submit

Tags: javascript, ajax, submit

Идея:

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var forms = document.getElementsByClassName('ajax_form');
  console.log(forms);
  var forms = Array.prototype.slice.call(forms, 0);
  forms.forEach(function(i, item, array) {
    item.onsubmit = function() {
      alert(i);
      // start ajax from here
      // by getting attributes from form.ajax_form
    }
  });
  
}
```

```html
<form class='ajax_form' url='/ajax/somewhere/' method='post'>
  <input name='test' send='1'>
  <input type='submit' value='send'>
</form>
<form class='ajax_form' url='/ajax/somewhere/' method='post'>
  <input name='test' send='1'>
</form>
```

onsubmit ничего не происходит. Предположение в том, что я преобразовал коллекцию html к массиву. Если это так то просьба показать как правильно (и красиво) перебрать коллекцию. Ответы просьба исключительно на **чистом javascript**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У Вас перепутан порядок параметров в обработчике `forEach`:

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var forms = document.getElementsByClassName('ajax_form');
  console.log(forms);
  var forms = Array.prototype.slice.call(forms, 0);
  forms.forEach(function(item, i, array) {
    item.onsubmit = function() {
      alert(i);
      // start ajax from here
      // by getting attributes from form.ajax_form
    }
  });
  
}
```

```html
<form class='ajax_form' url='/ajax/somewhere/' method='post'>
  <input name='test' send='1'>
  <input type='submit' value='send'>
</form>
<form class='ajax_form' url='/ajax/somewhere/' method='post'>
  <input name='test' send='1'>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var forms = document.getElementsByClassName('ajax_form');
  console.log(forms);
  for (i = 0; i < forms.length; i++) {
    forms[i].onsubmit = function() {
      alert(this.getAttribute('url'));
      // start ajax from here
      // by getting attributes from form.ajax_form
    }
  };

}
```

```html
<form class='ajax_form'  url='/ajax/somewhere/' method='post'>
  <input name='test' send='1'>
  <input type='submit' value='send'>
</form>
<form class='ajax_form' url='/ajax/som2ewhere/' method='post'>
  <input name='test' send='1'>
  
  <input type='submit' value='send2'>
</form>
```